# Linux: Tool to monitor every process, execute-command, shortly, monitor what's happening at the moment

Tags: linux, kernel, monitoring, logging, processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I log all process launches in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux)

Hello,
due to a freeze problem of my Ubuntu 10.10 (it is not isolatable) I though about logging every executable of the kernel somehow in any file to see what happens last when a freeze occures the next time to not lose valuable information.
I found acct but this is obviously not what I'm looking for. Actually it logs just user commands and those things. I need something which logs in a much "deeper" level. The best would be some kind of script which records every interrupt. Does anybody know some tool like that?

Comment: Audit subsystem.

Comment: i.e. start with http://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux

Comment: Maybe you can get a [kernel core dump](http://askubuntu.com/q/3051/1059). See also [CrashdumpRecipe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe) and other [Ubuntu kernel debugging topics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging).

Comment: Thanks Gilles, this is what I'm looking for. Can you post is as answer, so I can check it answered.

Comment: You can try 'execsnoop' from perf-tools. https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/execsnoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gilles' comment](https://superuser.com/questions/223184/linux-tool-to-monitor-every-process-execute-command-shortly-monitor-whats-h/231057#comment227114_223184) was the solution:

> Maybe you can get a [kernel core dump](https://askubuntu.com/q/3051/1059). See also [CrashdumpRecipe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe) and other [Ubuntu kernel debugging topics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You might try a 'ps' -aux that will list all processes running on the system at a point in time. You could put it into a shell script to iteratively run over time, probably with a sleep in between iterations. A 'top' runs continuously and lists the largest users of system resources. It also has flags that can tailor its output (man top or man ps)

Alan

Comment: ps is not low level enough. AFAIK it is not possible to get kernel interrupts with it. I will get auditd a try.