# Is it possible to log all files that are executed in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I log all process launches in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux)

I would like to be able to log all the files that are executed on my system, so I can see later in a log which files have been executed.

I tried the following guide: http://shibuvarkala.blogspot.com/2009/04/howto-enable-process-accounting-in.html but it doesn't work for me. If I follow the steps outlined, then fire up the calculator, for example, I can see that this process is running - and is called "gcalctool". Then I close it, but after doing this I don't see it in the list of commands output by "lastcomm [myusername]".

```
sudo lastcomm tty7
```

Doesn't work either, nothing is printed here (X is running on tty7).

Comment: Does [this](http://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux) help?